Azure AD B2C Run User Flow Fails
I'm setting up Azure AD B2C to use in my Web API and mobile apps. I set it up following the documentation provided by Microsoft here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview
When I created the Azure AD B2C tenant in my Azure subscription, it automatically added my account associated with my Azure subscription. I then tried to test my user flow by hitting "Run user flow" -- see image -- and used my account associated with my subscription since it's already added to the B2C tenant but I keep getting account not found error. Any idea why?

Here's the screenshot of the login screen where I use my account to test the flow:

Here's the users list where I can see my account:

Any idea why this is happening?

This is an ExternalAzureAD account.
If you click on the link, do you see #EXT# in the name?
This means it's not a local account, which is why you can't log in.
Go to New user / Create new external user and create a user and password.
This is a local account, and you will be able to log in.
